# Streaming audio and video into IOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, video, stream

I am creating an iPhone app on Xcode with build in video and music, the trouble is I want to keep the whole app below 20MB

I've compressed the videos to a OK standard but I'm still over the 20MB

Is there a way I can just stream the videos from a server, so when I click on my video / Audio button in the app it plays like it was saved within the app.

Many Thanks

Comment: why 20MB? App Store over the air restriction is 50MB - just saying..

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it changed, might have solved my problem

Comment: @Paul : How did you stream video from online? I wanted to know. Can you provide code or email me at parkarfahim22@yahoo.co.in

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://movieurl"]];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieView];
```

don't forget to import MediaPlayerFramework

If you need more control over streaming, playback or the view itself, see [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: When I add the code, the player opens for 1 second and then closes again, its as if its not finding the URL

Comment: try different URL and make sure the file type is supported.

Comment: Yep was the URL others are working, many thanks, if I want to stream my own mp3 into a iOS app, do I need to set up a cloud server and have a link,